# What does this mean: configuring Qt with “-opengl desktop”?

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading an [article](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/24/graphics-on-windows-from-a-different-angle/). I don't understand what this means: configuring Qt with “-opengl desktop”? How to do it? May I need to reinstall Qt with this option? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only applies when you're compiling the Qt libraries from sources. `configure` is a command you run to prepare the build environment right before you start compiling the Qt libraries yourself.

For example: [These](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html) are the configure options for Qt 4.8.